# Program that prompts user for any number of readings and terminates by entering a value that is not a number

Tags: python-3.x

Program in python that prompts the user to enter number of readings (including none) terminating their list by entering any value that is not a number

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
x=[]
x.append(input("please insert a number... "))

while((x[len(x)-1].isnumeric()) or (len(x[len(x)-1])==0)):
    x.append(input("please insert a number... "))
del x[-1]
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code loop will only stop if the `string` cannot be converted to `float`

```py
   while True:
        x = input('Enter a number: ')
        if x != '':
            try:
                float(x)
            except:
                break
```